# C# how to show message after specific time period

Tags: c#, timer

In my project I would like to show message or call methods after 5 minutes for example, If the users didn't click on specific button, I wrote this code

```
  Boolean flage = false;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer Clock;
        Clock = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        Clock.Interval = 1000;
        Clock.Start();
        Clock.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);

    }
    public void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs eArgs)
    {
        if (flage == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("after period of time ");
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flage = true;
    }
```

Its keeping show the messageBox can any body help me.

Comment: how could you ever expect a method to be called after `5 mins` when you have the Interval set as the following `Clock.Interval = 1000;`

Comment: The timer fires every second. That's what you asked for.

Comment: I set the Clock.interval=1000; just for test whether it works properly or not

Comment: So, in what way does this fail?

Answer (score 2):

Your Timer Clock variable is on the stack and ceases to exist when the function exits.

Try making it a member of the class.

Comment: No, you are thinking of C++. This is C#.

Comment: It will be garbage collected but not immediately.  I don't know if having an event handler attached will keep it marked as in use.

Comment: This is not correct. Empirically (as in I tried it) the above code works and does what is expected. I assume because although you lose the reference to it that it is referenced somewhere to be able to do the callbacks. So this is very much not true.

Comment: @SteveWellens You are contradicting yourself now. I suggest you edit the answer so that it is accurate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I am not contradicting myself.  Just because it works doesn't mean it will always work.  Do you know what happens if the object is garbage collected before the timer fires?

Comment: @SteveWellens: Yes because I just tried it. I called `GC.Collect()` on a third button and it had no effect on behaviour (ie it still kept popping up the dialogue on every tick). If you don't know what it does why not just test it?

Comment: @Chris - Calling GC.Collect() isn't enough for a valid test.  Remember the system will call Dispose (alright, it calls the Finalizer which then calls Dispose).  And when that happens, the timer event will not fire.  It may work 99.9999 percent of the time but there is a vulnerability.

Comment: Just to clarify: An event handler will _not_ prevent the object from being garbage collected.

Comment: @SteveWellens: OK. I'm a little hazy on garbage collection which is why I explicitly stated my test method. Is there a simple answer to what would need to be done to actual force the garbage collection of the timer? I assumed that if it didn't get disposed of by a call to GC.Collect() that it never would be...

Comment: @Chris - That is a great question sadly I don't know the answer.  I called dispose manually (which is what the Garbage Collector does indirectly and indeterminately) during my testing.